# How to make Visual Studio (2010, 2013, 2015) attach to iexplore.exe automatically

Tags: javascript, debugging

can you help me about how to make Visual Studio (2010, 2013, 2015) attach to iexplore.exe automatically.

I have three different Visual Studio versions (2010, 2013, 2015) installed on my (win 10 home) computer, these there versions have a same problem that every time when I ran web applications and tried to debug JavaScript code, I have to manually attach to the right iexplore.exe process (X86, Script one in the pic), I always have 2 iexplore.exe process running when I debug JavaScript code.

Do you guys know how to make Visual Studio attached to iexplore.exe (script) automatically?

Thank you.

[image: 2 Different iexplore.exe process]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i uninstalled windows 10 and installed windows 7 on my computer, this problem was solved. not just this issue, plus the IIS issue with never-stopping 503 error (service unavailable)

I know this seems like a dumb-ass way, but this is the only way after I tried a lot of days.